# nosql databases - what are these good for?

Tags: nosql

Recently I watched some old Oredev presentation on NoSql databases. I learned a bit but I still don't know when these databases are typically used. When it's good to use one and when it's not? Before I start learning any it would be great to know if there will be any opportunity to use one. Do You have suggestions on what db to try first? I'm working in .NET, learning some Ruby.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I learned a bit but I still don't know
>   when these databases are typically
>   used. When it's good to use one and
>   when it's not?

I would recommend to read for example these:

- [What Should I Do? Choosing SQL, NoSQL or Both for Scalable Web Applications](http://www.slideshare.net/toddhoffious/what-should-ido-11)
- [35+ Use Cases For Choosing Your Next NoSQL Database](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/6/20/35-use-cases-for-choosing-your-next-nosql-database.html)
- [The NoSQL Ecosystem](http://www.aosabook.org/en/nosql.html)

> Before I start learning any it would
>   be great to know if there will be any
>   opportunity to use one.

Opportunity knocks at the strangest times. It's not the time that matters but how you answer the door.

> Do You have suggestions on what db to
>   try first?

If you have .NET background try to look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial) or [CouchDB](http://oreillynet.com/pub/e/1790). Answer to this question however may depend on what is your scenario or what is the nature of your problem where you want to apply NoSQL solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can read something about:

[The Big List of NoSQL Use Cases](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/02/the-big-list-of-nosql-use-case.php)

I think that [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a good starting point.

[Getting Started with MongoDB and C#](http://jasona.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-c/)