# Database for read and append only

Tags: database

Basically my application needs to dump data daily into a database. But for any data written down, there is no need to update.

Hence, is appending to csv or json file sufficient for the purpose. Or it will be more computationally efficient to write in standard SQL?

**Edit**
Use-Case Update
I am expecting to store one entry of for each particular activity count daily. There are about 6-8 activities.

It is exactly like a log in some sense. I would like to perform some analysis with the trend of activities for example. There is no relations between different activities though.

If say in some cases there might be a need for update, would that imply a proper database will be more suitable rather than text file?

Comment: The information you provide is insufficient so give you any meaningful advice. How much data will be generated? What are the usage patterns? Will it be updated/read by more than one process?

Comment: if you didn't like SQL Database, and you don't need transactions, replication and etc..just store data, you could dump your data to files: it's simplest and fastest solution. For more detailed answers, please give more view to expectations, what you would do with data next, except storing them.

Comment: according to update: if you need to use database, answer depends on data size, a small and mid sized data - Relation database can handle this, but for big data which only grown NoSQL solution would be preferable, More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640025/nosql-databases-what-are-these-good-for).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the data, but there may be another style of database other than an SQL one which could be suitable, like MongoDB which essentially stores JSON objects.
SQL is great when you need entities to have relationships to each other, or if you can take advantage of the type of select queries it can provide you with.
Database systems do have some overhead and could have some gotchas you might not expect, like loading up a heap of crap into memory so it's ready to be searched.
But storing text files can have drawbacks, like it might become difficult to manage your data in the future.
It basically sounds like your use-case is similar to logging, in which case dumping it into a file is fine.